# C# Result Window like in Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I have been a Powerbuilder as long as I can remember. I am fond of using DataWindows and DataStores so my techniques really relies on this. As I am now trying to learn C#.. I found out that I can use DataGrid and ListView. But the problem when I am using DataGrid is I cannot make it look like ListView, and the problem in ListView, I cannot click it by row and column. I can only highlight the rows in Column A.

Is there any DataWindow like in C#, that I can also do dw.Filter() , updated, insert, delete.. etc...

Comment: Nothing really unless you pay some dough, and they still don't compare to the datawindow. Too bad SAP dropped the ball with PB worse than Sybase did.  I just wrote an article on my blog about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

We use DevExpress controls as well (within our PB apps even...), and the XtraGrid is very powerful, and looks very slick, especially compared to PB's built-in controls.  DevExpress controls are not free, though!

Comment: thats what I cannot afford. So I am guessing there are no freebies in C# development that can make a life easier?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DevExpress controls. I think between the XtraTreeList and the XtraGrid you can get what you want. You will have to bind them to an external data source. They don't have one built in as the DataWindow does. These are Windows Forms controls. There are similar controls for WPF and other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old question but there is a pretty clear-cut answer to the question. No, there is nothing in the .NET framework that has functionality like the datawindow.

The DataGrid is like a 3rd generation control compared to DataWindow which is like a 4th generation control.

This is the reason that complex business applications, or applications more complex than sample applications are so much more time consuming to develop in .NET. You do have the option of buying 3rd party tools, but you will have an inferior product AND you'll need to fork out cash.

Telerik has some nice controls but they are quite expensive and there is a slight learning curve, not to mention they still do not compare to the datawindow.